# Castle Windsor lifestyle for web-service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Let us suppose we are injecting instances of web-services via Castle Windsor. What is the scenario when I want to use Transient lifestyle for them or PerWebRequest one? What is the way to think? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a new instance of a component every time you request one from the container, use Transient.  If you want the same instance to be pulled from the container throughout the life of a single web request, use PerWebRequest.